# Get Contact React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, contacts, native-module

I want to make a screen page that can be navigated in the contact list on my phone. so I made a native module for get contact, It worked but for android 10 and below. For android 11 he can't run. The function I created can't get contact data.I've made sure all the permissions are there. Below is the code I made

```
const getChooseContact = () => {
    const { ContactsWrapper } = NativeModules;

    ContactsWrapper.getContact()
      .then((contact) => {
        setPhoneNumber(contact.phoneNumber);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

const requestMediaPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
      );

      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        getChooseContact();
      } else {
        setErrorMessage('Access media permission denied');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Could you please add what is happening? Do you see an error?

Comment: no errors, function ContactsWrapper.getContact() not work in android 11 @p-syche

Answer (score 0):

This is majorly because in API 30 and above we can no-longer interact with external modules without specifically being allowed the interaction.
This can happen in two ways one using the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />` inside the androidmanifest.xml though this is discouraged since it can have your app rejected Read this kindly https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-query-all-packages-permission

to fix your issue

1. inside build.gradle under android update class paths to this :
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4' this allows for the next step to be recognised during bundling otherwise your will get an error
2. inside  androidmanifest.xml before the  application tag add this

```
 <queries>
        <!-- Browser -->
        
        <intent android:label="View Contact">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" android:host="contacts" />
         
        </intent>


    </queries>
```